# Why would IE repeatedly send GET requests for an image when outside of compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, web, asp-classic, get

I'm troubleshooting an issue with an ASP web app which only occurs in Internet Explorer when not in compatibility view. In compatibility view it works fine and it works in Firefox and Chrome as well. It appears that the page is loading slowly, but in the network tab of the developer tools I can see that it is executing thousands of GET requests for a particular image file which are all coming back successful. I can't imagine why this would be happening.

Here is a screenshot of the network tab so you can see what I mean. In this example, IE made more than 6,000 successful GET requests for the same file.

[image]

**EDIT:** Since @pherris asked in the comments, the image is referenced in the CSS as the `background-image` property for buttons (`background-image: url(../images/btn_background.gif);`).

**EDIT 2:** So I figured out where the number of requests is coming from. The page is displaying a grid which contains 2054 rows of data. Each row contains three buttons as well as the actual data. Each button uses the above CSS which loads the `btn_background.gif` image. So since `2054 * 3 = 6,162`, that explains the ~6,000 requests for that image. However, why would IE request the same file that many times rather than simply request it once? This only happens in IE when not using compatibility view. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: How is the page requesting the image? did you look at the HTML/JS?

Comment: @pherris, The image is referenced in the CSS (`background-image: url(../images/btn_background.gif);`.) I'm not sure how the HTTP request gets made behind the scenes. Is there any other information that might be helpful?

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to page your grid, based on maybe 25 to 50 rows and provide a search facility to speed up the process.

Comment: Have you looked at the cache headers for the image?

Comment: @Paul, we actually have a newer version of this same page which does use paging for the grid, but this client is demanding support for the older version of the screen because it better suits their business need.

Comment: @jwnace: Blimey! That's a lot of info some poor soul has to go through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the etiquette for answering my own question, but I found the cause of the problem. There was another CSS property on the buttons which was causing the requests to happen:

```
/* The -ms-filter fits the image for IE8. */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/btn_background.gif', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

I'm not familiar with `-ms-filter` but I did some googling and it's a deprecated MS specific CSS property. I found it because I was looking for all references to `btn_background.gif` so I could replace them with the data URI scheme as suggested by @pherris and I saw that it was being referenced in this property as well. I commented it out and sure enough, the page works perfectly now. I even fired up a VM with IE8 on it and tested it there and there are no issues there either even though the comment indicates that this property is being used for IE8 compatibility.

Comment: The ettiequte is its encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the headers sent back with the image and troubleshoot the specific IE version you are using, but at this point I would suggest simply base64 encode the image in your CSS. This will avoid even one http request (for the image) and you can make the change entirely on the client.

The CSS would change to something like this (where the string is the encoded image):

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
```

To base64 encode your image, you can use an online converting tool:

http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @pherris. I tried this and while it was still doing the same number of requests, they were significantly faster (<1 ms). This could be a good short term fix.

Comment: Can you post the HTML HEAD contents? what instructions are you sending the browser for caching?